# Django | Pasar parámetro 'modalidad' por url para filtrar en Views.py ¡Error!

Tags: python, django, django-models

Al pasar por url como parámetro una modalidad (celador, o administrador) para poder filtrar en el view según esa modalidad me da error. ¿Cómo debería ser? ¿Tengo un planteamiento erroneo?

**Enlaces:**

```
<a href="{% url 'test' ciencia %}"></a>
<a href="{% url 'test' historia %}"></a>
```

**url.py:**

```
path('test/modalidad', pregunta_views.pregunta, name="test")
```

**views.py:**

```
def pregunta(request,modalidad):
    preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(modalidadPreguntas=modalidad)
    return render(request, "pregunta/pregunta.html",{'preguntas':preguntas})
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

La solución (o almenos una de ellas) es poner en el template los enlaces con los argumentos con comilla simple como se muestra. Y en url.py duplicar para dejar el 'test' intacto y el del argumento como se muestra en el ejemplo con :

**Enlaces:**

```
<a href="{% url 'test' 'ciencia' %}"></a>
<a href="{% url 'test' 'historia' %}"></a>
```

**url.py:**

```
path('test', pregunta_views.pregunta, name="test")
path('test/<srt:modalidad>', pregunta_views.pregunta, name="test")
```

**views.py:**

```
def pregunta(request, modalidad):
preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(modalidadPregunta=modalidad)
return render(request, "pregunta/pregunta.html",{'preguntas':preguntas})
```